# How to remove seconds from Python datetime object?

Tags: python

I have a python datetime object that I want to display on a website, however the time shows in the format hh:mm:ss and I want to display it in the format hh:mm.

I have tried using the replace method as per the following:

```
message.timestamp.replace(second='0', microsecond=0)
```

However this doesn't get red of the seconds it just replaces it with hh:mm:00

Answer (score 10):

Use [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 27, 11, 14, 37, 137010)
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime("%H:%M")
'11:15'
```